# "USe Android as a remote" option won't stay selected in Mythbuntu Control Centre

Tags: mythbuntu

When I try to connect to my Mythbuntu machine using Mythmote on Android, I get the following error:

> IO Except: /192/168.0.4:5456 - Connection refused: 192.168.0.4

At first I thought it was the same issue as [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127445/mythmote-wont-connect-to-mythbuntu-12-04-seems-frontend-is-not-listening-on-all), but, I've now discovered a problem on the Mythbuntu side.

When I go into `Mythbuntu Control Centre -> Infrared Romotes and Transmitters`, it has `No Additional Remote Support` selected. Despite the fact that I selected `Use Android or iOS phone as a remote` last time I looked at it.

If I try to select `Use Android or iOS phone as a remote`, when I hit `Apply`, it says "No changes found". If I login and out, or reboot, it reverts back to the `No Additional Remote Support` option.

How do I get my `Use Android or iOS phone as a remote` option to stick?

Comment: For what it's worth, I noticed the setting didn't stick either, so I'm not entirely sure that's the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say I have the same problem, however it seems similar: On atom box running latest 12.04.1 ubuntu kernel.

When boot up I exit frontend. and then go to control-centre. Open it and select Infrared control and remotes; I select Android and then apply - it says nothing to do (this is OK).

I then leave control-centre in this state (it seems there is a bug as the code to wroite out the selection does not work).

Goto menu and select front-end and wait for start. Select watch and away you go. Mythmote now connects!!!